# Port Redirection not working (80->3306)

Tags: database, linux, redirect, forwarding

i have got a new Linux Server (Debian 6.0) with a Database (MySQL) which is accessed by Port 3306 like as usual.

Now I'd like to access the database due port problems of some users (because port 3306 is often blocked by network firewalls) by port 80 or 443. So the transfer must be redirected from Port `80` to `3306` to keep the Database working.

I have tried following command:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 3306
```

but I got following error:

> iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.

Does anyone can help me solve this problem? The NAT table is empty (`PREROUTING`,`POSTROUTING`,`OUTPUT` have no entries) (checked with `iptables -t nat -n -L`)

Comment: It should work (that is, unless you compiled your own kernel, disabling things you don't understand, etc.)

Comment: no i haven't compiled my own kernel, should i do so (compile the kernel)?

Comment: no, you should not (and there is no need to install any modules if you're using a sane distribution (which, btw?))

Answer (score 1):

## In iptables Kernel modules required for NAT functionality:

Run following command to load modules in kernel:

```
  # modprobe iptable_nat
  # modprobe ipt_REDIRECT
```

Make sure you have above modules compiled in kernel:

```
[root@instructor tmp]# grep REDIRECT /boot/config-$( uname -r )
CONFIG_IP_NF_TARGET_REDIRECT=m
CONFIG_BRIDGE_EBT_REDIRECT=m
```

**In VPS Server:**

Enable modules on host server using `modprobe` command

Execute following command from the host server to enable all the modules for the `VPS`

```
vzctl set VEID --iptables iptable_nat --iptables ipt_REDIRECT
```

Add rules in file `/etc/vz/conf/veid.conf`

```
IPTABLES="iptable_nat ipt_REDIRECT"
```

Comment: thanks for your help but I cant execute the grep command because the boot directry is empty. (has no folders or files). is that normal?

Comment: root@srv01:/# modprobe iptable_nat
WARNING: Deprecated config file /etc/modprobe.conf, all config files belong into /etc/modprobe.d/.
FATAL: Module iptable_nat not found.

Comment: Why don't you tell us about your OS and kernel version. Something is teribally wrong.

Comment: I believe you are using VPS server isn't it? I believe you can't load kernel module in VPS.

Comment: In VPS you need to load module in HOST machine not container machine.